# Copy QueryString Parameters of all sessions in Fiddler to a file for Web Analytics Automation

Tags: automation, fiddler, web-analytics

I want to copy QueryString parameters present in sessions of Fiddler to a file and then compare them with an excel sheet where a list of parameters are present. If the parameters in that list matches with the parameters received from Fiddler then test case will pass otherwise fail.

But I am unable to retrieve the parameters from Fiddler in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler's menus have the command **File** => **Save** => **Selected sessions** => **As text** also ... => **As text (headers only)**. They output (as the command name suggests) text files. It is then be a relatively simple task (in Perl or Python or many other programming languages) to extract and format the pieces needed.

Comment: I want to dynamically test the presence of parameters in the file. But the problem is the parameters are dynamically changing and I do not have access to code. No idea how can it be automated

Comment: Your question states *"I want to copy ... of Fiddler to a file ..."* and my answer shows how you can do that. What does *"and I do not have access to code"* mean? Is it possible that your question needs a lot more explanation of what you are trying to do?